# For given ID(Key), How to convert dynamic rows values into columns in oracle 11g SQL. Need to use PIVOT and sum aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot, aggregate-functions, crosstab

```
ID        PaymentLateBy        Amount

1111      30 days over        1000
1111      90 days over        3000
1111      90 days over        2000
1112      45 days over         100
1113      120 days over        900
1113      On Schedule         1000
1113      120 days over        500
```

Results I need is as following

```
ID        On_Schedule  30_days_over   45_days_over  90_days_over 120_days_over    

1111      0            1000            0            5000         0
1112      0            0               100          0            0
1113      1000         0               0            0            1400
```

I am very new to coding SQL. I have been trying to play with this code for sometime. Need desperate help as I do not know anyone personally whom I can reach out for. I would really appreciate your help from this community. This is my first question and post.

```
select * from (
select t.ID, t.PaymentLateBy, t.Amount
      from tbl1 t 
)PIVOT
( 
 sum(t.Amount)
 FOR t.PaymentLateBy IN ('On Schedule', '30 days over', '45 days over', '60 days over', '90 days over', '90+ days over', '120 days over','120+ days over')
)
ORDER BY t.PaymentLateBy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
select id,
       COALESCE(on_schedule, 0) AS "on schedule",
       COALESCE(days30, 0)      AS "30 days over",
       COALESCE(days45, 0)      AS "45 days over",
       COALESCE(days90, 0)      AS "90 days over",
       COALESCE(days120, 0)     AS "120 days over"       
from   tbl1
PIVOT( 
  SUM(Amount)
  FOR PaymentLateBy IN (
    'On Schedule'   AS on_schedule,
    '30 days over'  AS days30,
    '45 days over'  AS days45,
    '90 days over'  AS days90,
    '120 days over' AS days120
  )
)
ORDER BY id;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (ID, PaymentLateBy, Amount) AS
SELECT 1111, '30 days over',  1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1111, '90 days over',  3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1111, '90 days over',  2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1112, '45 days over',   100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1113, '120 days over',  900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1113, 'On Schedule',   1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1113, '120 days over',  500 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | on schedule | 30 days over | 45 days over | 90 days over | 120 days over |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1111 | 0 | 1000 | 0 | 5000 | 0 |
> | 1112 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
> | 1113 | 1000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1400 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94f85e19e0bf214ebc5d4964b44d4d8d)*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to share this solution. But I am getting  error when I use this example and map it to my code "ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here:"

Comment: @Pp8801 It works in the db<>fiddle linked in the answer. You will get that error if you are not using simple column names in the `SELECT` clause; you probably need to move the pivot into a sub-query but unless you share the code (or a [MRE]) I can't tell you what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional (`CASE`) aggregation (`SUM`):

```
SQL> select id,
  2    sum(case when paymentlateby = 'On Schedule'  then amount else 0 end) on_schedule,
  3    sum(case when paymentlateby = '30 days over' then amount else 0  end) "30 days over",
  4    sum(case when paymentlateby = '45 days over' then amount else 0  end) "45 days over",
  5    sum(case when paymentlateby = '90 days over' then amount else 0  end) "90 days over",
  6    sum(case when paymentlateby = '120 days over' then amount else 0  end) "120 days over"
  7  from tbl1
  8  group by id
  9  order by id;

        ID ON_SCHEDULE 30 days over 45 days over 90 days over 120 days over
---------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------------ -------------
      1111           0         1000            0         5000             0
      1112           0            0          100            0             0
      1113        1000            0            0            0          1400

SQL>
```